# Java : How to append x-times method to the object instance?

Tags: java

I have the following snippet:

```
// Create URI object first
        JSONObject requestParamsObject = null;
        if (requestParams != null) {
            requestParamsObject = new JSONObject(requestParams);
        } else {
            Logger.i("Params variable is null");
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.scheme("http")
                .encodedAuthority(url)
                .appendQueryParameter("username", "test")
                .appendQueryParameter("password", "password")
                .appendQueryParameter("version", "2.3");
            url = URLDecoder.decode(builder.build().toString(), "UTF-8");
            Logger.i(url);
        }
```

I would like to use these methods:

```
.appendQueryParameter("username", "test")
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", "password")
                    .appendQueryParameter("version", "2.3");
```

To append the methods using the for cycle.

**FXP:**

```
// Set params to request
        Map<String, String> mRequestParams = new HashMap<>();
        mRequestParams.put(Constants.Login.PARAM_URL_KEY_USERNAME, username);
        mRequestParams.put(Constants.Login.PARAM_URL_KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        mRequestParams.put(Constants.Login.PARAM_URL_KEY_APP_VERSION, "2.3"
```

**To use by similar way like this:**

```
mRequestParams[i]
.appendQueryParameter(RequestParams[i].key, RequestParams[i].value)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: How about using using recursion, where you pass in your data in some collection, probably hashmap

Comment: Could You please add some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("http").encodedAuthority(url);
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mRequestParams.entrySet()) {
  builder.appendQueryParam(entry.key, entry.value);
}
url = ...
```